# Block Gas Limit Doubt

Tags: gas-limit, gas-estimate

Suppose i have a loop.
Here user is a struct of which player is an address.

```
address[] memory addrs = new address[](n);
for(uint i=0;i<n;i++){
addrs[i] = user.player;
}
 return addrs;
```

This is a view function so i know i wont have to pay to run it.
Is this going to fail if the value of n increases beyond a point?
Im confused about the gas block limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you use it.

If you are calling it from your backend system through a node there is no gas limit as the call never goes inside a block. The call is simply made to the node and the node returns the required information - the blockchain network is not consulted at all. So the only restrictions are your node's throughput and computation power.

However if you call such a function from a non-view smart contract then the regular gas limits and gas payments are in place. So, yes, if your `n` is too big then you will hit the block gas limit and/or transaction gas limit at some point.

Comment: ok so if i call it from my frontend ,this wont cause an issue as long as its a view function?

Comment: Yes, that is correct